# How to change the color of the navigation bar for the iOS 5 platform?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uinavigationcontroller

I am having some trouble changing the background of the navigation bar for the iOS 5 platform in XCode 4.3.2 . I prefer to not set the background as an image. Can someone post how to do this and how to change it for the whole app? I want to change it to a light blue color.

Thx

Comment: I'd give an answer right now, but I wonder if Apple will be providing an official API to do this with the about-to-be-announced iOS 6?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann am I missing a joke or is this a flashback to when iOS5 was released - surely the `tintColor` appearance property does this?

Answer (score 1):

In `application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your application delegate, add the following:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Substitute your favourite colour. See [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html) for more things you can adjust. This changes the appearance of all navigation bars in your application.

Comment: where would I implement something like this?

Comment: does it matter if you put it in the .h file or the .m file?

Comment: Is this what the code would look like?

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return YES;
}






I get an error Property 'tintColor' not found on object of type 'id'

Comment: Thanks a lot jrturton. Is there like a list of blue colors that I can work with as well?

Comment: You make your own using [UIColor colorWithRed:... or whatever you like. See UIColor class reference for details.

Answer (score 0):

Look at iOS 5's [UIAppearance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol. It's iOS 5 only, but gives you a very good way of customizing a lot of UIKit elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the tintColor property.

Comment: Where can I find this tint property because I cannot find it. Been searching for something like this before. Is there a way to make the color of the navigation bar stay constant for the whole app or do I have to individually set it for each view controller?

Comment: It is a property of the NavigationBar. (cf [documentation]http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html)

jrturton answer seems right to me concerning the whole app part.